# Need advice regarding deployment on multiple remote machines

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, build-automation, msdeploy, remote-server

Currently I am using ms-deploy to build and deploy on several machines using team-city. In my current scenario, I need to build, package and deploy on Dev. After this I need to deploy this package on test and Live servers (which are on different domain. I understand how we do it but problem is Web transformation only occurs for test and live configs if we build a package. It means if I want to use the same package that is created for Dev cannot be used, as web transformation only occurred for Dev web config. Also know that we can change web config when un-packaging but that parameters are very limited. We have a lot of changes not just the connection string or db changes. 
Another solution is to add another step to build packages for test and live as part of Dev deployment but then it means a lot of copying on remote servers, once for test and once for live which is a lot of time consuming due to different domains.

Can you please guide what is the best solution in this scenario. So I can use team-city to publish to Dev and test and live using same package and different web configs in one go.

Answer (score 1):

To configure items at deployment time which are not automatically created for you.  You can add a file named parameters.xml to your project and extend what you want to make available at deployment time.

Here's some documentation on the approach [Using Deployment Parameters for Web.Config File Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068.aspx).

Comment: Can you please guide. If I use deployment parameters then we don't need the web transformation configurations. Also will it contains what ever setting I need to replace. e.g application setting, changing paths in various keys and names. Can I use it with teamcity